# Cannot verify nonce

Tags: nonce

I create nonce as

```
$nonce = wp_create_nonce("action");
```

And then send the email with nonce to user. In the email there is the link to a page. In the page I form the nonce the same way and try to verify it using

```
wp_verify_nonce($nonce, "action");
```

, and it doesn't work, it always fails to verify, and returns false. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing wrong is using nonce in a context it was not intended to be used in. nonces should be used on web pages for logged in users, not just a random "it has something to do with security so it has to be right" kind of measure ;).

If you need to validated the authenticity of the link you have sent, just use an md5 hash (or any other hash generator) based on whatever long term "secret" information you have on the user. At the best case, nonces "live" for 48 hours, while emails might be opened later then that.

Comment: So for nonce to work, the user has to be logged in?

Comment: I tried to go to the same page that does the verification logged in, and it still doesn't verify the nonce.

Comment: I need to secure the page that only the user that I sent the email to can access what I want him to access. You suggest I should store the md5 value somewhere manually, instead of using nonce native wordpress functionality?

Comment: it does not validate because the user used at nonce generation is probably not the one used when you access the page, therefor nonce will fail. You can probably work around it but in the end of the day it is just the wrong way to do this

Comment: ok, so I should instead make a custom sort-of-nonce generator that will create and check hashes, much like a login form does, yes? Which MD5 generator function can you recommend me maybe? Thanks, I really need this.

Comment: just use `md5` it is not the best, but doesn;t sound like you need high level of security. The issue you are facing is specific to how wordpress generates and validates nonces. If it was truly a "one time value", you could have used the API, but since it is not, and the values are time limited, it is just not appropriate to anything which might not happen "right now"

Comment: Did it, it works (off course). Wanted so hard to use native wordpress nonce though :)

Comment: so I should only use wordpress nonce for linking between pages when a logged in user browses between them, if I understood correctly?

Comment: In a way yes. If a nonce expires while the user legitimately takes time to conclude an operation, it just makes a bad UX (try to keep any wordpress admin page open for more then a day and do some operation after that and you will see how annoying it can get), therefor it is just wrong to just use it everywhere without thinking first whether you want it to expire in the first place. Nonce should protect against attacks in which people craft requests and trick user to send them to change their settings.

Comment: .... therefor if it is not a user, and the request is not changing any settings, you need to think carefully if the use of nonce is beneficial at all. A good example in contact forms, you work so hard to make people contact you, it is not smart to force them resend a request just because a nonce expired.